# Send GPS data Every 10 Minutes

Tags: iphone

```
(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

// Override point for customization after application launch.

locmanager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init]; 
[locmanager setDelegate:self]; 
 [locmanager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters];
//[locmanager setDistanceFilter:10];
[locmanager startUpdatingLocation];

[window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation       *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation 
{ 

 CLLocationCoordinate2D loc = [newLocation coordinate];
  latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%f", loc.latitude];
    longitude= [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%f", loc.longitude];
//Call to the web service for sending data

}
```

I am trying to send data from Iphone to a web service every 10 minutes.The code I have written  sends the data but I cannot set the interval.I have registered to use Location services in background in my application so it keeps on running the application even after I close my application.Could anyone suggest me how should I proceed.I am new to iphone programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use following test code;

NSTimer *updateTimer;

```
updateTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:10 target:self selector:@selector(startUpdating) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:updateTimer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

in startUpdating method, you have to write below statement;

```
[locmanager startUpdatingLocation];
```